# Routes With Custom Domains Using Flask

Tags: python, flask, subdomain, werkzeug

My web app assigns a subdomain to users and optionally allows them to use a custom domain.  This works except when the user visits their custom domain for a route without including a trailing slash.

GET requests to this url works as expected:  `http://user.example.com:5000/book/12345/`

GET requests to this url works as expected:  `http://custom.com:5000/book/12345/`

GET requests to this url attempt to redirect, but fail:  `http://custom.com:5000/book/12345`

Flask ends up redirecting the browser to this url which, of course, doesn't work:  `http://<invalid>.example.com:5000/book/12345/`

Is there a different way that I should handle custom domains?  Here's a complete minimal example to reproduce this.  I have set custom.com, example.com. and user.example.com to point to 127.0.0.1 in my /etc/hosts file in my development environment so that Flask receives the request.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

server = app.config['SERVER_NAME'] = 'example.com:5000'

@app.route('/', subdomain="<subdomain>")
@app.route('/')
def index(subdomain=None):

    return ("index")

@app.route('/book/<book_id>/', subdomain="<subdomain>")
@app.route('/book/<book_id>/')
def posts(post_id, subdomain=None):

    return (book_id)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='example.com', debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that's possible. host matching and subdomain matching are [mutually exclusive](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#maps-rules-and-adapters) (look at host matching parameter).

I'd love to be wrong though.

One way around this issue that I can think of is to use something in front of Flask (say nginx) that points `custom.com` to `custom.com._custom.example.com` or something like that. In your code you could create a custom `url_for` function that would recognize this as a custom domain. I would ask on the Flask [mailing list](http://flask.pocoo.org/mailinglist/) as they would be able to give you a solid answer.

Comment: That's a good suggestion.  I just did emailed the Flask list.  Thanks.

Comment: Please let us know the answer you get.